# Listbox html helper returning zero objects to Post function

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, listbox, html-helper

I trying to get a listbox for a module I've created to work. The selector works (the titles of the selectable entities appear but there is no data returned to the Post function in the controller.

I don't know what you would need to be able to help me, but here is at least the html code.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="field required">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sessions)
        @Html.ListBox("Sessions", new SelectList(Model.Sessions, "Id", "Title", 1));
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sessions)
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not `ListBoxFor`, therefore it's not binding the value to any property on `POST`. If it's a `SelectList`, bind it to an `int`, something like `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SessionId, new SelectList(Model.Sessions, "Id", "Title", 1))`, where in your model the SessionId would be an int property - the index of selected item in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I changed it to this: @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.Sessions, "Id", "Title", "1")) but I'm still getting null to the Controller. The module "Session" does not contain an integer ID property, but I tried using a SessionViewModel that does, and that didn't work either. Any ideas ? Am I maybe able to do this in a simpler fashion ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ViewBag` in `Controller`

```
ViewBag.Sessions = new SelectList(EntityName, "Id", "Name", entity.ID);
```

`entity.ID` will be value which you want to select

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sessions", "Select Sessions")
```